# TFS 2018 - Set permissions for single dashboard

Tags: security, tfs

In TFS 2018 on-premises server, is it possible to set permissions for a single dashboard, separately from the other dashboards in that project?

I have multiple dashboards in my main project and I would like to give only a few specific users access to edit one of those dashboards, but all users should have the ability to view it.

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. In the UI of TFS 2018 the `Permissions` tab of the `Manage Dashboards` dialog you can only configure if team members in general can view, edit or manage dashboards.

This dialog can be opened clicking the wrench symbol in the top bar on the right.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/dashboard-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=previous-nav&viewFallbackFrom=vsts),

> As a member of the Project Administrators group, you can set the
> default dashboard permissions for all teams. As a team or project
> administrator, you can set individual dashboard permissions for team
> members. The permissions only affect the team members to which the
> dashboards belongs.
>
> By default, all team members have permissions to edit dashboards
> defined for the team. All other valid users of the project have view
> only permissions, except for members of the Project Administrators
> group. You can change the default permissions a project from the
> Project settings.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/_img/set-permissions/project-setting-permissions-prev-nav.png?view=vsts))</sub>

[image]

Comment: Yes I saw this article too but the screenshot doesn't correspond to TFS 2018 on-premises server (looks more like Azure DevOps screenshot), and I am looking to restrict access for only one specific dashboard in this project.

Comment: @blizz the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/dashboards?view=vsts&tabs=previous-nav) mentioned that it can support TFS 2018. Could you try updating the latest version of TFS 2018 which is RC3

Comment: I already have TFS 2018 Update 3. It does not look like that screenshot.